# ASP.NET MVC 5 - No intellisense .cshtml files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've looked around a bunch trying to fix this. I thought it was a problem in my `web.config` (both in root and in views/), however the problem still persists in new solutions I make through Visual Studio.

[image]

The error reads: `The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context.`

I've tried re-installing visual studio, messed around with versions in web.config for hours, uninstalled packages with nuget. The whole lot.

Here is my root Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Web.config file for CleanApp.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies/>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here is my Views/Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="CleanApp" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And for good measure heres my packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I am running Visual Studio on Mac. Some info:

[image: image info]

Please let me know if you need more info. I've read a load of articles both on blogs and even here on Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work. That's why I created this with my specific issues.

The linked files are from a brand new project, generated through visual studio, not editing.

Comment: .net version conflict .

Comment: @AsifRaza Thanks for the response. Could you advise where to start looking to fix this?

Comment: targetFramework="4.5" you can change it as previous.

Comment: @AsifRaza So i should change my target framework for the entire project? Do you have any recommendations as to which version? I can't go back to 4.0 because not all of my packages are compatible.

Comment: Go back .. as intial you did

Comment: @AsifRaza I think project was initially in 4.5.